# StageWebView for accessibility

Tags: apache-flex, accessibility, stagewebview

I'm struggling with my flex application where I'm rendering the HTML pages through `StageWebView`.  I need to add accessibility to it, however, it doesn't seems like accessibility is supported in the `StageWebView` component.

Any recommendation of what to do here? I need it in both mobile and desktop app.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add accessibility"?

Comment: I would like my air application be able to use the accessibility tool (NVDA or JAWS) to read the html content.  Or is there anyway I can render a html page and read the content through a flex air app?

Comment: The answer to all of your questions is likely that you can't. You have zero control over `StageWebView` and you cannot access the content rendered inside it or communicate with that content in any way whatsoever. Additionally, it is the only reliable way to render HTML data in Flash (you can try `HTMLLoader`, though in my experience, it is hardly an acceptable way to render HTML)